# Execute inline code within org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am creating a table in org-mode to be exported to a beamer slide. To some of the cells, I would like insert values evaluated in R.

```
|           | Mean dose^{*} | Doses           | Est. % Escalated                               |
|-----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------|
| Celecoxib | 209 \pm 37    | {200, 400^{**}} | src_R[:session *R* :exports results]{p_cele}   |
| Naproxen  | 852 \pm 103   | {750, 1000}     | src_R[:session *R* :exports results]{p_napro}  |
| Ibuprofen | 2045 \pm 246  | {1800, 2400}    | src_R[:session *R* :exports results]{p_ibupro} |

Embedding in a regular text (src_R[:session *R* :exports results]{p_cele}) works ok.
```

In this example, the inline src_R below the table works, but the ones within the table is not recognized as code snippets to be executed. p_* are variables created in a preceding code block.

[image]

Comment: This is very old. Since then my workflow evolved to do the table construction within R and then export the table as a LaTeX table using the xtable package.